# How to do session on login Screen in android with the help of Facebook developer kit?

Tags: android, facebook, session, authentication

I am using Facebook developer kit to login my app through mobile number.But once i close the app,its asking me to login again .I need to handle session.Suggest me How to do it?????

I want to handle session,i.e once the user logins he should not be ask again to login until he/she logouts or reinstall the app..

Answer (score 0):

you can create a login session with shared preference like this:-

create a AppPreference class like this :-

```
public class AppPrefrences {

    private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;

    public static boolean isUserLoggedOut(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return mPrefs.getBoolean("id_logged_in", true);
    }

    public static void setUserLoggedOut(Context ctx, Boolean value) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.putBoolean("id_logged_in", value);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
}
```

and now login in your app and call the method from app preference class :-

```
setUserLoggedOut(YourActvity.class, false);
```

and now on every time on your splash screen set a check like this :-

```
if (isUserLoggedOut(StartActivity.this)) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
```

this is what i am doing in my every app.